# mmap a 10 GB file and load it into memory

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

if I want to `mmap` a 10 GB file and load the whole file into physical memory immediately, how can I do so?
I don't want to use function like `mlock` because it needs root privileges.
Is there a system call which can satisfy my demand?

(I have more than enough memory.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [man-page for `mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> #### MAP_POPULATE (since Linux 2.5.46)
>
> Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping.  For a file
>     mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  Later accesses
>     to the mapping will not be blocked by page faults.
>     `MAP_POPULATE` is supported for private mappings only since
>     Linux 2.6.23

Issue your request, and be prepared for a short wait (unless you exceed the processes limits) (depending on disk-bandwidth and cache).

Comment: +1 To add to this, you can alternatively `madvise(MADV_WILLNEED)` if you can't be bothered to block inside `mmap`. You are of course giving up the "instantly present" guarantee, but the whole range will still be immediately loaded into RAM, just asynchronously. Though unless you `mlock` successfully, you never have a guarantee anyway (pages may be swapped out or discarded at any time), so that may be acceptable.