# Non-lazy file read using mmap?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory, mmap

When you use mmap to read from a file, it performs lazy file read, that is it brings only the data that you use from the hard disk to RAM. Now, is there any method with which we can force the whole file to be read into the RAM at once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mmap a 10 GB file and load it into memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727209/mmap-a-10-gb-file-and-load-it-into-memory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `mmap(2)` man page:

> **MAP_POPULATE** (since Linux 2.5.46)
>
> > Populate (prefault) page tables for a mapping.  For a file  mapping, this causes read-ahead on the file.  Later accesses to the mapping will not be blocked by  page  faults.   **MAP_POPULATE**  is supported for private mappings only since Linux 2.6.23.